# Como puedo agregar desde

Tags: c#, highcharts

Como puedo agregar varios arreglos de datos a `.setseries` de un `highchart`?

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series x = new Series();
                    x.Name = "test";
                    x.Data = new Data(aux_series_progreso.ToArray());
                    chart.SetSeries(x);
```

tengo este ejemplo pero solo puedo agregar uno, pero se necesitan n arreglos

Comment: en php es algo asi  array_push($series, $array_datos), cual seria su equivalente en C#?

Comment: .SetSeries(new[]
                    {
                        new Series { Name = maquina["nombre"].ToString(), Data = new Data(aux_series_producido.ToArray()) },                
                    new Series { Name = "OBJETIVO", Data = new Data(aux_series_progreso.ToArray()) }                   
                    }); algo asi pero dinamico o desde programacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar una lista de series para agregar las series y luego el `SetSeries()`, algo como esto:

```
var serie1 = new Series(){ 
    Name = maquina["nombre"].ToString(), 
    Data = new Data(aux_series_producido.ToArray()) 
};

var serie2 = new Series() { 
    Name = "OBJETIVO", 
    Data = new Data(aux_series_progreso.ToArray()) 
}


List<Series> series = new List<Series>();
series.Add(serie1);
series.Add(serie2);

chart.SetSeries(series.ToArray());
```

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, hasta que tuve el gusto y honor de que atendieras una pregunta mia, efectivamente eso resolvio mi problema